# php remove element from array without add key

Tags: php

I want to remove an element from an array (converted from json), but with unset, and reconvert in json, the array become indexed.

Source array:

```
{"rows":
[{"c":[{"v":"Date(1409052482000)"},{"v":22},{"v":22},{"v":22},{"v":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(1409052614000)"},{"v":22},{"v":22},{"v":22},{"v":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(1409052782000)"},{"v":22},{"v":22},{"v":22},{"v":null}]}
]}
```

Result:

```
{"rows":
"2":{"c":[{"v":"Date(1409052614000)"},{"v":22},{"v":22},{"v":22},{"v":null}]},
"3":{"c":[{"v":"Date(1409052782000)"},{"v":22},{"v":22},{"v":22},{"v":null}]}
}}
```

the problem is the "2" and "3" keys. I don't want this keys, because I use the data for google chart, and is sensible for this index key.

PHP code:

```
$tempdata = json_decode($jsonTempLog, TRUE);
foreach ($tempdata['rows'] as $key => $row) {
    if ( $logtime < $showtime) {
        unset($tempdata['rows'][$key]);
    }
}
echo json_encode($tempdata);
```

How can I remove element from array, keep the original json syntax?

Comment: What is $logtime and where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i work with :

```
unset($infos[$i]);
$infos = array_values($infos);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works: $tempdata['rows'] = array_values($tempdata['rows']);

Answer (score 4):

Just do this:

```
$tempdata["rows"] = array_values($tempdata["rows"]);
echo json_encode($tempdata);
```

Otherwise JSON thinks you're sending an associative array rather a numeric one

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
foreach($tempdata as $row){
    $tempdata[$rows['keyfield']] = $row;
}
```